# what does the cortex-M4's initial SP value in the 0x0 use for?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, startup, cortex-m

through the Cortex-M4 Devices Generic User Guide, could find a initial sp value in the 0x0.

through startup_stm32l431xx.s, could find

```
Reset_Handler:
  ldr   sp, =_estack    /* Set stack pointer */ //LDR loads a register with a value from a PC-relative memory address.The memory address is specified by a label or by an offset from the PC.
```

so,my question is why there is still has initial SP value in the 0x0 because we already done the initial sp value in the startup_stm32l431xx.s(i think startup.s one of work is initial sp value)

Since we always set sp in the startup code, why do we still have an address of 0x0 to store the initial sp value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question, and my guess is that this initialization is redundant since since 0x0 does contain `_estack`, as you mentioned, and that this value will be automatically loaded at reset into `sp`, the same way `pc` will be loaded with the addresse for `Reset_Handler`: For example, the equivalent code for the arm compiler does not contain any additional code loading `sp`: the gcc version of the startup code is the only one to use such a redundant initialization: you can compare The [gcc version](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/blob/v1.18.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32l431xx.s) (the one I am assuming you are referencing), the [arm version](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/blob/v1.18.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Source/Templates/arm/startup_stm32l431xx.s) and the [iar version](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/blob/v1.18.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32l431xx.s).

Comment: Question 1: In the arm version, who sets the value of sp? Can I set it in any way? (If I want to customize my stack)

Question 2: How is this initial value automatically loaded into the CPU? Is there an instruction at 0x0 for the CPU to execute, thereby loading the SP value into the CPU?

Comment: Question 3: Does the automatic loading process start as soon as the CPU is powered on? (Does the CPU start fetching instructions from 0x0 as soon as it is powered on? If I just power on the CPU without pressing the reset key, does the CPU start fetching instructions from 0x0, then continue to PC+1, and finally execute reset_handler, which leads to an indirect reset?)

Comment: The stack pointer register is set to whatever value is in [0x0] automatically by hardware before the first instruction of Reset_Handler, so this ldr instruction in Reset_Handler can be removed.  The CPU always starts executing at the address given in [0x4], no matter what type of reset (pin reset or power on reset).

Comment: @jackwen  You should ideally post new questions as new questions, not as comments to one specific answer to a different question.  Re. Q1, see in the startup.s file the vector table starts `.word _estack`, where `_estack` is a _linker symbol_.  You will have a linker script .ld (for GNU toolchain) that creates that symbol.

Comment: @jackwen  Q2. That is part of the Cortex-M reset logic. Q3. Yes, load SP, Jump to reset vector (the first two words in the vector table).  There's an un-numbered Q4 there:  The "reset button" asserts the /RESET pin, power-on causes a Power-on Reset (POR) - they are both reset events.  You could also have watchdog resets or NVIC resets - all the same in the h/w behaviour.  A reset is a reset, the causes differ. Other things happen on reset; simply setting the SP and jumping to the reset vector in code is not the same as a reset.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the hardware initialisation of SP on reset is to allow start-up source code to be written in C - with constraints such as not requiring static initialisation, or standard library initialisation to have occurred, and where the entry point is not `main()`.

A typical Cortex-M start-up is:

```
; Reset handler
Reset_Handler   PROC
            EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
            IMPORT  __main
            IMPORT  SystemInit
            LDR     R0, =SystemInit
            BLX     R0               
            LDR     R0, =__main
            BX      R0;
            ENDP
```

where `SystemInit` is typically a C function that has the same constraints, however if it ran directly via the reset vector, it would have to be responsible for calling `__main` creating a call stack that included `SystemInit()`'s own stack frame that could not then be reused by the runtime until returning from `main()` which would be unusual and normally an error.

So it makes sense if you are running a full C runtime with a `main()` entry point to *not* jump directly to `SystemInit()` to maximise available stack space, and in that case it would be unwise to assume that the build tools used set the initial SP in the vector table appropriately for the sake of one instruction to *be certain*.

I have never seen the ability of Cortex-M to boot directly to C code used, but for very simple applications with no C runtime library requirement it may  be useful.